# Serialization of an unknown object

Tags: c++, qt, serialization, boost

I've been looking for something capable of serializing totally unknown objects.

I know that Qt has a [serialization](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/datastreamformat.html) feature that also works with [qvariant](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qvariant.html) objects. Does that mean that I can pass a whatever complex object to a QVariant (i.e. something that also has pointers and/or pointer cycles) and serialize that object?

It also seems [boost::any isn't supported by serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3672315/3834459).

Is this impossible to do without writing my own specific-type-serialization routine due to the lack of reflection in C++?

Comment: What do you mean by "unknown object"? Can you edit your question with an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @wasthishelpful `unknown object` means `unknown object`.. it could be any type of C++ object you can find on github on any project of your choice.

Comment: That's not unknown, that's undefined, maybe undeclared :) That's why I'm asking for an example of how you want your final code to be working, to figure out what your unknown means from a compiler perspective

Comment: @wasthishelpful something that compiles in your program and that you can pass to a `template<typename T> void serialize(T&& obj);` function.

Comment: A `QVariant` can't hold arbitrary types. From [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qvariant.html): "The QVariant class acts like a union for the most common Qt data types."

Comment: @molbdnilo you can add user defined objects to QVariant by registering them as metatype. I think you still need to declare your class as QObject.
edit: added [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE),
pointers would obviously have to be reconnected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is impossible to do this without writing your own serialization code, because C++ does not have reflection. You, pretty much, figured it out.

Comment: QVariant is just a union of different types, but if you use a custom type, you still need to tell Qt about it.  Check out this tutorial http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QVariant_meta_object_system_MetaType.php

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize any `QVariant` as long as all the types you expect the `QVariant` to carry have their `QDataStream` operators defined. So, for custom types of your own, you need to have these operators in place and then it'll work fine.

Answer (score 0):

While C++ does not have reflection, it is possible to get limited reflection in Qt if you QObjects and the [Qt Property System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/properties.html).

It is fairly easy to write code to serialize and deserialize all of the properties of any QObject.  [hint: There are methods to retrieve all properties of a QObject.]  The trade off here is that everything you wish to serialize must be a QObject (and QObjects can not have a copy constructor), and your getters and setters must work with properties.  With some clever macros, this is not too big an issue from a coding standpoint.